# Unable to upgrade firefox in ubuntu

Tags: 11.10, upgrade, firefox

I tried these 3 commands to upgrade my firefox version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

But it doesn't seems to be work out.

and i also did try by this link which is purely manual step process
I don't find any option as in this link.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/update-firefox-latest-version.

Please let know the way to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Mitch:  let me know the way to highlight the commands in the question. Which will useful for me in posting the question further. Thanks

Comment: What is the  output of `sudo apt-get install firefox?` and for your question regarding the "highlight": You do that by adding two of thees --> `` one on both sides of the text.

Comment: for more info on how to format follow this link: 

[editing-help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install firefox`

[sudo] password for Blue: 

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree 
    
Reading state information... Done

firefox is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 557 not upgraded.

Comment: **...Done firefox is already the newest version...** Seems Firefox is up to date. :)

Answer (score 1):

To install the latest Firefox in Ubuntu 11.10, download the desired file either the 32Bit or 64Bit package depending on your system from [Here](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/oneiric/main/updates/firefox).  Once downloaded, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to where the file was downloaded, and run the command below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

As far as your comment on how to highlight the commands in the question, just type the command(s), and press the `<$>` on top of the box.

[image]